# create jrxml file at run time and modify at run time

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement to develop custom reports where we already have some reoprts developed using JasperReports using iReport tool. Now the requirement is to modify those reports design at run time. I should use those existing jrxml files and save as to new report then change the design at run time. Also I should see those newly created reports whenever I want.

I have gone through the Jasper API and Dynamic Reports where we can create the reports dynamically at run time but we can't save the design (like JRXML).

I am looking for any other JRXML design API to create and modify and save the Jasper Reports at run time.

I appreciate if any one can help me.

Thanks in Advance
Srinivas

Comment: @Bozho: Hi! I have exactly the same requirement to make. Can you please tell me how in the end have you resolved and implemented this???? I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Julia I'm not the asker of the question. @Srinivas is

Comment: @Bozho.....sorry, mixup between edited and asked. In any case i looked into dynamic jasper, so that seems to be best solution as far. Have you recommended it because you used it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/docs/HOWTO%20export%20to%20jrxml.html) can do this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you will need to draw a flow chart of how you want to do things.

For example, if the report already exists, and you want it as is, what will you do?
In case you want to modify it a little, do you want to save as `jrxml` and compile each time?
Or do you want to compile to `jasper`, store on local storage then populate later.

It seems you want to build a reporting engine and answering all those questions is basic. In that case here is something to start from.
Find a factory called `DocumentBuilderFactory` which will help you parse the XML into DOM object, modify then save it.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/445.cfm) on using it

Comment: Hi Medopal,

Thank you very much for your answer

As you mentioned in the 2 point that it will similar like reporting engine because I need to create another JRXML based on my old jrxml at run time and modify then save. I need to show all the reports (modified and original) on screen to user then he can export when ever they want. 
You said DocumentBuilderFactory from DOM. Do you any other API (May be from Jasper) to create and modfiy jrxml at run time? I found some JRXMLWriter and JRXMLReader but I don't whether these works for me or not.

Please help me if you know anything